# Why is my MVC 5 application trying to access Local DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-sql-database, localdb

I have been developing an MVC 5 application on my local machine, and having just tried to public a test version to Azure, I have found this new error.  My connection strings have no reference to a LocalDB, and I can't find anything in my code that wants to create or access a LocalDB.  Yet I am receiving an error related to an attempt to create/access localDB:

> The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database location within the application's App_Data directory

Originally the project had forms authentication, but I later changed to AspNetIdentity framework.  I'm concerned I've got some residue from the initial template with forms authentication that I cannot find despite combing the application several times and googling at length.

Here are the connection strings.  There are no others.  At least using a find function in Visual studio to look for "connectionString" - this is all:

```
<add name="elmah" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:xxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User ID=xxxxx@xxxxx;Password=xxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="IdentityDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:xxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User ID=xxxxx@xxxxx;Password=xxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="ORLODbContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ORLODbContext.csdl|res://*/ORLODbContext.ssdl|res://*/ORLODbContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=tcp:xxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User ID=xxxxx@xxxxx;Password=xxxxx&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

My googling has led me to add these other features to the web.config.  In the `system.web`:

```
<authentication mode="None" />
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
  </providers>
</profile>
```

Here, my googling also suggests I should add:

```
<roleManager>
  <providers>
    <clear />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

But if I do this, I get the error:

> Default Role Provider could not be found.

Seeing as I don't want one, it seems, I thought maybe I don't need this bit.  But please correct me if I'm wrong.

Is there anything else I should look at?

Comment: These errors are happening on your Azure instance? (You mention you've been developing local, which i presume is fine, which leads me to believe these new problems are when you go to publish).

Comment: Yes, Brad, you assume correctly - works fine on local copy on my PC.  When publish to Azure, I encounter this problem.

Comment: Is it possible you have a connectionString defined in your azure instance (either through an azure publish project or directly through the azure portal?) **EDIT** You may also try standing up a single .aspx page that dumps out `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` just to see if there's anything unexpected.

Comment: That's a really interesting idea.  I've just tried it on my local version, and I have found an extra connectionString!  It's name is "LocalSqlServer" and it points to the LocalDB.  So, obviously this is in my configuration and is carrying over.

Comment: @nulliusinverba No, like I said in my answer, that connection string is coming form your `machine.config`. Every `web.config` file inherits from there.

Comment: Sorry David, I understand what you've said I was unclear with my language there.  Indeed, you've found the issue and I've marked your answer correct.  Thanks so much for your brilliant help!

Comment: I would also like to note that with the solution in place from below, with the correct web.config settings, the LocalSqlServer connection string still appears in the list pulled up from `System.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` on my local machine.

Comment: It will still appear unless your web.config does a `<clear/>` of the connection strings.

Comment: And now that I've done that, it has indeed gone entirely away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asp.Net by default uses the role manager, even when working with Identity. The solution is to disable it completely. In your `web.config` remove the entire `roleManager` section and replace it with:

```
<roleManager enabled="false" />
```

For some further info, in your `machine.config` you likely have a line like this:

```
<add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"
    connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="..."/>
```

And a connection string like this:

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer" 
    connectionString="...localdb..." 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

So leaving the role manager entries in there make Asp.Net start looking in this local db before your `IdentityDbContext`. Removing the entries means it tries to fine an entry and fails. So the only solution is to disable it completely.

Comment: That seems to have done it!  The original error is now gone.